# Road Graph doesn't find shortest path

Tags: qgis, road, shortest-path

Road Graph plugin in QGIS does not find the shortest path except when the feature is a single line. This might be due to the fact that I've used different CRS for layer and project while I edited the roads layer. Is there any way to find the shortest path in such situation. I've used snapping, but the Road Graph documentation reads:

> It is required to use layer CRS as project CRS while editing roads layer. This is due to the fact that recalculation of the coordinates between different CRS introduce some errors that can result in discontinuities, even when the «snapping» is used.

Comment: What do you mean with "when the feature is a single line"? Can you provide some sample?